# Can't connect to NetTcpBinding WCF service due to "There was no endpoint listening" error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

Could you guys please point what I'm missing here ?

I have two sample projects. Both console applications (.Net 3.5). Here is "server" side:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var baseAddresses = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9000/WcfServiceLibrary/svc");

        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(UiWcfSession), baseAddresses);

        var reliableSession = new ReliableSessionBindingElement { Ordered = true, InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue };
        var binding = new CustomBinding(reliableSession, new TcpTransportBindingElement()) { ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue };

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IClientFulfillmentPipeService), binding, k.WinSvcEndpointName);
        host.Open();

        Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
    }
}
```

Not sure if it's important but here is small snippet of `IClientFulfillmentPipeService`

```
  [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof (IClientFulfillmentPipeServiceCallbacks), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
  public interface IClientFulfillmentPipeService
  {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Initialize(int uiProcessId, string key);
  }


  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IClientFulfillmentPipeServiceCallbacks
  {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ShowBalloonTip(int timeout, string tipTitle, string tipText, BalloonTipIcon tipIcon);
  }
```

and finally client

```
    private void OpenConnection()
    {

        try
        {
            var ep = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9000/WcfServiceLibrary/svc");

            var reliableSession = new ReliableSessionBindingElement {Ordered = true};

            Binding binding = new CustomBinding(reliableSession, new TcpTransportBindingElement());
            reliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            var pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IClientFulfillmentPipeService>(this, binding, ep);
            commChannel = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

            ((IChannel) commChannel).Open(OpenConnectionTimeout);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.ErrorFormat("The communication channel to the windows service could not be established.  {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The client fails with `System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException` exception which says: *"There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:9000/WcfServiceLibrary/svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."*

This is modification of production code which is using named pipes and I want to convert it to Tcp transport.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally left `k.WinSvcEndpointName` in the endpoint definition in the server. That was the problem.